# How do sedevacantists who claim the See has been empty since Vatican II understand the legitimacy of the bishops and priests?

Tags: catholicism, sedevacantism

I was recently listening to my favorite Catholic apologist Trent Horn talk about Sedevacantism on his podcast, and he brought up an objection that I’m curious to hear a response too. He said that if the See was truly empty since Vatican II, and becoming a priest/bishop required the laying of hands by other legitimate priests/bishops, then no current priests/bishops except for the ones ordained prior to Vatican II (I think he said it was 4 ministers) would be legitimate. Thus none of the sacramental distributions would be legitimate either. How would a Sedevacantists respond to this?

Answer (score 3):

Sedevacantists say that there is a "bishop in the woods" still out there that was consecrated by what they think is the last valid pope (usually Pius XII). Supposedly this saves the visibility of the Church and apostolic succession, but they can't identify who this last valid bishop is.

Currently, the [oldest bishops in the world](http://www.catholic-hierarchy.org/bishop/sage2.html) seem consecrated no earlier than 1961, under John XIII (e.g., [Bishop José de Jesús Sahagún de la Parra](http://www.catholic-hierarchy.org/bishop/bsahagun.html)).

One of [the last Pius XII-consecrated bishops](http://www.thetradforum.com//index.php?topic=519.0), [Dominik Kalata, S.J.](https://www.catholic-hierarchy.org/bishop/bkalata.html) (consecrated 1955), passed away 23 August 2018. [Manuel José Bernardino Piñera Carvallo](https://www.catholic-hierarchy.org/bishop/bpinc.html) (consecrated 27 April 1958) died 21 June 2020. [Pius XII](https://www.catholic-hierarchy.org/bishop/bpacelli.html) died 9 October 1958.

See "'Bishop in the Woods' Theory", pp. 69-72 of [*True or False Pope? Refuting Sedevacantism and Other Modern Errors*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=5904). Cf. also: *[Sedevacantism: A False Solution to a Real Problem](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=8889)*.

Related:

- [Crisis Series #34 w/ Don Tranquillo: Is Sedevacantism the Answer to the Crisis?](https://sspxpodcast.com/2021/07/crisis-series-34-w-don-tranquillo-is-sedevacantism-the-answer-to-the-crisis/)
- [Papal Heresy and Loss of Office - SSPX Interview Series](https://sspxpodcast.com/2022/02/papal-heresy-and-loss-of-office-sspx-interview-series-fr-macgillivray/)

Comment: That’s a pretty bad objection from them - not sure how one bishop in the woods can be traced to all the existing ministers

Answer (score 3):

The following describes the position of most sedevacantists (as far as I know), including me. There may well be other sedevacantists who hold the theory described by Geremia, and there are also some who hold some theories about being able to elect a pope on their own.

Bishops consecrated before the current situation (sede vacante) began have consecrated more bishops since then, some of whom have consecrated yet more bishops. (For example, Archbishop Marcel Lefebvre consecrated four bishops in 1988.  Archbishop Ngo Dinh Thuc also consecrated new bishops.) All these bishops can not only consecrate more bishops when needed but can also ordain priests. So there is no problem about having validly consecrated bishops and validly ordained priests.

As far as I know, the new church considers these consecrations valid but illicit, because they lack papal permission.  Sedevacantists and some other traditionalists consider them licit because of the need to provide the sacraments for the faithful and the impossibility of obtaining papal permission. (Even those traditionalists who consider Bergoglio a valid pope realize that there's no chance of his permitting consecration of a bishop who fully adheres to the Catholic faith, i.e., pre-Vatican II.)

Comment: Does this make Bergoglio an antipope in sedevacantist eyes?

Comment: Surely this does not account for all bishops.

Answer (score 1):

I intend to be concise, not abrasive; therefore, please do not take my tone as anything other than direct.

Distinctions and terms matter.

**I was recently listening to my favorite Catholic...**

According to whom/what? That is implicit though indirect question-begging; your bias is showing. If "The Sedevacantists" are correct, then Mr Horn, as a so-called Apologist, *the entity he represents and defends, and his methods **are not Catholic.***

In other words, you tacitly assume that he and his "Church" are correct from the outset. Why bother asking your question then? (See "Reflex principle" for a germ of a possible, sound response.)

**... becoming a priest/bishop required the laying of hands by other legitimate... priests/bishops...**

False premise: it does not. Please make the distinction between sacramental *validity* and *liceity,* i.e., "legitimacy." In other words, conferring (*valid*) holy orders, *licit or otherwise* requires at least one ***validly** consecrated bishop,* not a *licit* or even *Catholic* one.

We may easily demonstrate this from, for example, two facts:

1. Even Trent Horn acknowledges that the so-called Eastern Orthodox have always had *valid* sacraments. However, at least up to "Vatican 2," the Church did (and does) not consider them *licit,* as She (The Church) thinks the "Eastern Orthodox" *schismatic.* (See 1054 AD)
2. The (Catholic) Church, again at least pre-"Vatican 2", formally declared that the Anglican orders are *invalid.* (See, e.g., https://www.newadvent.org/cathen/01491a.htm)

As at least one premise is false, the rest does not follow. Thus, this question is DoA.

**How would a Sedevacantists respond to this?**

Sadly, we are not monolithic, which would follow in an instance of, for example, a vacancy of the Holy See.

I hope that helps. At least I am a Sedevacantist. First-hand beats second, yes?

I advise you to go to vaticancatholic.com with further questions.

Comment: PS, re your curiosity: https://www.newadvent.org/summa/3167.htm

Comment: Trent horn is an apologist for Catholic Answers, I just included that bit to give context for my question.

Comment: While that may have been what you intended, words like "my favorite Catholic apologist " is more than just context; it is a glaring endorsement of the individual as a "Catholic apologist" and, indirectly, of his organisation as Catholic.

Ironically(?), "Trent horn is an apologist for Catholic Answers" would be a better, factual contextual statement, granting that calling a duck a dog does not take out the quack, re "Catholic," again.

If we are not honest and careful, we will not make it. Mind your soul, bro(?), the way is narrow.

Comment: @LukeHill has been open about his own perspective. He has heard something which appears to be an argument against sedevacantism, but rather than simply accept it, he has asked for the sedevacantist response. That is very admirable and appropriate for this site.  YP Poe you ask Mr Hill to distinguish between validity and liceity. I think you have identified the best answer to Mr Hill's question. But it is for you, as the answerer, to make that distinction and explain its significance. Non-legitimate does not mean invalid. Can you link evidence for this, because that is how this site works?

Comment: Are you link-blind? Regardless, if beggars want to choose, then they can starve. My response was sufficient; I am not here to author a thesis. Mr Hill, as a professed unconfirmed Catholic, can practice studiousness if he is interested in anything more than having his ears scratched. (see "curiosity," prev) The Church commands such. Finally, who are you to say if I have done my job? By what exact criteria? Hey, it's your job... #Arbitrary #Hypocrisy #PostPolice

Or are you asking if that is how the site works 'cuz asserty question marks and reasons following an ambiguous assertion? #Ambiguity

Comment: This is the first time someone other than a school administrator or my mother has called me “Mr. Hill”, I love it :)

Comment: I'm just trying to be polite but, cool.